# Why does my Powershell script print the same string for both user inputs?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

New to shell scripting, so trying to learn, I have written the following script:

```
Write-Output "Would you like to create a text file?"
$userInput = Read-Host "Y [1] Or N [2]? "

if ($userInput = 1)
{
Write-Output "Create file"
}
elseif ($userInput = 2)
{
Write-Output "No file created."
}
else
{
Write-Output "Incorrect entry."
}
```

Selecting Option 1 prints out `Create file` as expected.

Select Option 2 also prints out `Create file`, which is not expected.

Is is due to a quirk with how `Read-Host` works with saving variables, or am I using the wrong module for this task?

Thanks very much!

Comment: `=` is assignment, for comparison you want to do `-eq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change with -eq operator (not use "="), below the code:

```
Write-Output "Would you like to create a text file?"
$userInput = Read-Host "Y [1] Or N [2]? "

if ($userInput -eq 1)
{
Write-Output "Create file"
}
elseif ($userInput -eq 2)
{
Write-Output "No file created."
}
else
{
Write-Output "Incorrect entry."
}
```